# ExpressJS API PUT returning 200 but not updating MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, angular-fullstack

I've got an ExpressJS API endpoint  built using [angular-fullstack-generator 4.0.1](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack). When I send a PUT request on existing data, the API returns 200, but there are no changes in the MongoDB - the data remains the same. I've never had an PUT return 200 with no change in data. GET and POST work fine with no problems.

I'm very new to the MEAN stack so I may be missing something very simple here.

**server/api/response/index.js:**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var controller = require('./response.controller');

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', controller.index);
router.get('/:id', controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
router.put('/:id', controller.upsert);
router.patch('/:id', controller.patch);
router.delete('/:id', controller.destroy);

module.exports = router;
```

**server/api/response/response.model.js:**

```
'use strict';

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

var ResponseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    created_at: Date,
    userResponse: Object
});

export default mongoose.model('Response', ResponseSchema);
```

**server/api/response/response.controller.js:**

```
//...
// Upserts the given Response in the DB at the specified ID
export function upsert(req, res) {
  if(req.body._id) {
    delete req.body._id;
  }
  return Response.findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true, runValidators: true}).exec()

    .then(respondWithResult(res))
    .catch(handleError(res));
}
//...
```

**GET api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f result:**

```
{"_id":"57aa6b6845078181549f703f","userResponse":{"name":"BOB","age":"30","existsOtherPerson":"There will be me and others","howManyOthers":"","ownedHomeBefore":"","shortSaleOrForeClosure":"","foreClosureYearsAgo":"","proceed":"","deadend":"","shortSaleYearsAgo":"","proceed2":"","deadend2":"","neitherShortOrForeClosureOverThreeYearsAgo":"","haveBankruptcy":"","bankruptcyType":"","dischargeYears":"","proceed3":"","deadend3":"","incomeSource":"","timeAtJobMoreThanTwoYears":"","timeAtJobMonths":"","previousEmployerPaidHow":"","previousEmployerGrossPaycheck":"","2WeekPaycheck":"","havePartTimeJob":"","partTimeJobMoreThan2Years":"","partTimeJobPaidHow":"","partTimeJobGrossPaycheck":"","otherIncomeSources":"","hasCashAssets":"","cashAssetValue":"","hasPropertyAssets":"","stillOwnPropertyAssets":"","propertyAssetMonthlyPayment":"","propertyAssetYearsOfPayments":"","hasRetirementAssets":"","retirementAssetsValue":"","monthlyRent":"","monthlyCreditCard":"","hasCarPayment":"","monthlyCar":"","hasStudentLoans":"","monthlyStudentLoan":"","deferredTime":"","hasOtherMonthlyPayments":"","creditScore":"","coApplicantReady":"","coApplicantFirstName":"","coApplicantEmail":"","phoneNumberFutureContact":"","phoneNumber":"","otherCoApplicantsReady":"","firstCoApplicantFirstName":"","firstCoApplicantEmail":"","secondCoApplicantFirstName":"","secondCoApplicantEmail":"","phoneNumberFutureContact2":""},"__v":0}
```

Now for the PUT.

**PUT api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f *Response Headers***

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=SmZRj04bTAc1zhijJcLgy4QKncvNxLjQ%2Fy7pI%3D; Path=/
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag: W/"574-DCUb4YAsIHkEpBlFCHSNCQ"
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Date: Wed, 10 Aug 2016 03:12:26 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

**PUT api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f *Request Headers***

```
PUT /api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f HTTP/1.1
Host: app.uxweb.io
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1415
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: [obfuscated]
X-XSRF-TOKEN: fDud34CMs0GLqzSXkrJwKAlM1ixcaQ9jPVssE=
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Referer: [obfuscated]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: connect.sid=s%3AcGP8M4iYpBJfABQke0vbr_X7oRoghAkr.Y%2B%2Fd7eroLXstvl0a3EszESDlJHIje%2BcFN6z7hozoK64; _gat=1; _ga=GA1.3.1959951694.1470779005; XSRF-TOKEN=fDud34CMs0GLqzSXkrJwKAlM1ixcaQ9jPVssE%3D
```

**PUT api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f *Request Payload*** Note how I made some changes (added a howManyOthers, etc)

```
{"_id":"57aa6b6845078181549f703f","userResponse":{"name":"Kite","age":"30","existsOtherPerson":"There will be me and others","howManyOthers":"2 more people","ownedHomeBefore":"","shortSaleOrForeClosure":"","foreClosureYearsAgo":"","proceed":"","deadend":"","shortSaleYearsAgo":"","proceed2":"","deadend2":"","neitherShortOrForeClosureOverThreeYearsAgo":"","haveBankruptcy":"","bankruptcyType":"","dischargeYears":"","proceed3":"","deadend3":"","incomeSource":"","timeAtJobMoreThanTwoYears":"","timeAtJobMonths":"","previousEmployerPaidHow":"","previousEmployerGrossPaycheck":"","2WeekPaycheck":"","havePartTimeJob":"","partTimeJobMoreThan2Years":"","partTimeJobPaidHow":"","partTimeJobGrossPaycheck":"","otherIncomeSources":"","hasCashAssets":"","cashAssetValue":"","hasPropertyAssets":"","stillOwnPropertyAssets":"","propertyAssetMonthlyPayment":"","propertyAssetYearsOfPayments":"","hasRetirementAssets":"","retirementAssetsValue":"","monthlyRent":"","monthlyCreditCard":"","hasCarPayment":"","monthlyCar":"","hasStudentLoans":"","monthlyStudentLoan":"","deferredTime":"","hasOtherMonthlyPayments":"","creditScore":"","coApplicantReady":"","coApplicantFirstName":"","coApplicantEmail":"","phoneNumberFutureContact":"","phoneNumber":"","otherCoApplicantsReady":"","firstCoApplicantFirstName":"","firstCoApplicantEmail":"","secondCoApplicantFirstName":"","secondCoApplicantEmail":"","phoneNumberFutureContact2":""}}
```

**Express console**

```
(node:23321) Warning: a promise was created in a handler but was not returned from it
PUT /api/responses/57aa6b6845078181549f703f 200 23.753 ms - -
```

When I do GET again, it's the same result before the PUT. What could I be doing wrong?

Please let me know how I can further clarify this question.

---

**EDIT**: Once I flatten my Model and payload, the PUT works. So the problem lies with how Mongoose updates Objects.

Comment: try `...findOneAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}, {...`

Comment: Thanks @libik, I'll give it a shot in a couple hours

Comment: @libik It still does not update... Any other ideas?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution. I am dealing with this same problem today